# Extract past and real-time twitter data from Topsy

Tags: twitter, extract, topsy

I am trying to extract all the tweets with the specific hashtag from Topsy. However, neither Topsy API Key nor Otter API are available. Could you suggest a data source and a way to extract the tweets please?

Thanks in advance,
convulsion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Topsy is no longer accepting new customers.  You should be able to get what you need from Datasift or gnip.  It will cost you, though.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! I am a student and want to use it for Master thesis.. Nothing for free?

Comment: They may have free or reduced cost for academics.  I suggest you visit their websites and check it out for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up on topsy.com using your twitter ID. I signed up on twitter just a week ago and I signed up on topsy.com using twitter account. (I did that right now)